# Casque bose qc35II non reconnu

Tags: bluetooth, software-recommendation

Bonjour, mon casque bose n'est pas reconnu je n'ai rien installer pour l'instant, je voulais avoir votre avis avant, j'ai regarde très vite sur internet les topics mais pas grand chose.
Merci d'avance

Comment: Question posted here should be in English. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour,

J'ai aussi eu un problème de connexion avec un casque SONY WH-1000XM3, si avec Elementary OS tu n'arrives pas à bien synchroniser un casque, une enceinte... bref un dispositif audio le mieux est d'installer blueman

```
sudo apt install blueman
```

Lance l'application

[image]

lance une recherche

[image]

Sélectionne ton casque

[image]

Lance la configuration

[image]

---

**Initial Problem**

Can't pair headphones

**Solution**

Install blueman